# Maximum number of unix donaim socket that can run in the same time on linux

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, libc, libc++

What is the maximum number of unix domain socket that linux can manage in parallel, besides the file descriptor limit that we can change?
Some Os have a limit https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/ztpf/1.1.0.15?topic=considerations-unix-domain-sockets

I am getting Too many open files os error.I didn't reach the NOFILE Limit.

Comment: I am not aware of Linux having an explicit limit, but I don't find any documentation expressly disclaiming one.

Comment: @Anis – 
I wonder why you need that many sockets in one process, given that one-to-many communication is doable over one socket.

Comment: @Armali I dealing with legacy code where I use one SOCK_DGRAM in a server for each connection to another. I randomly hit a hidden limit it seems.

Comment: How did you check how many files were open at the point of failure?

Comment: we are tracking the number of open fds on the host it is 50k  than the maximum set for the process is 200k

Comment: Can lack of memory cause this issue , I checked and I may have memory issue .